# Can I add my customized property page in projects created in RCP application

Tags: eclipse

I created a project in RCP application
right click on the project, in the "properties" dialog. Can I add my own Customized property page?

Comment: Look at the `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages` extension point

Answer (score 1):

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages` extension point to define new property pages. Something like:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages"> 
    <page 
        id="my.id" 
        name="Page Name" 
        class="package.MyPropertyPage"> 
        <enabledWhen>
         <instanceof
              value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
         </instanceof>
      </enabledWhen>
    </page> 
</extension>
```

which defines a property page which is show when a file is selected.